# Scrollbar causes bottom padding

Tags: css, scrollbar

So I started building a page with a form and I immediately ran into a problem when styling the footer. Because of vertical scrollbar on the page (which I am almost certain is causing it) the page has some sort of "padding" that leaves the footer with `bottom:0;` hovering about 40px above the bottom of the page.
is there any way to fix this without having to use `overflow:hidden;`?

The following is the HTML and the CSS.

```
<div class='center-column'>
  <h2 class='address_box-title'>This is the title that I wish to give this piece of work</h2>
  <textarea class='text_input'></textarea>
  <p class='content'>This is a slice of text that I'm serving up to you as a placeholder for all the fabulous content that will be put in here later on.</p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

and the CSS:

```
html{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}


footer{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  margin:0;

  bottom:0;

  height:12%;
  width:100%;
  background-color:red;

}



.center-column{
  height:auto;
  width:32%;
  /*this line is a result of me not knowing yet how to center things horizontally*/
  margin:2em 0px 0px 30%;
}


textarea.text_input{
    border: solid;
    background-color:#62ddfc;

    overflow:hidden;

    margin-bottom:8%;
    padding:20px 25px 0px 25px;

    height:4em;
    width:100%;

    outline: none;
    color:white;

    font-size:22pt;

    resize: none;
}

textarea:focus{
  border:none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}


.address_box-title{
  font-family:"sans-serif";
  font-size:28pt; 
  width:auto;
  margin:20px 2% 10px 2%;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately your code does not reproduce the issue. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/tygzLt3m/). No matter if I resize the result pane so that the scrollbar is present or not, the footer is always at the bottom. (Well, until I scroll anyway; you may have intended `position: fixed`). So can you make a [mcve] that does demonstrate the problem?

Comment: oh sorry I forgot to add something that is probably important to know, ,this code was in a code pen. I would have linked it but as always, stack exchange blocks it.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Leviathan_The_Great/pen/eywGqz

Comment: I may have forgot some crucial code then, the original codepen is here^

Comment: Sorry, but in the codepen I can't seem to find the problem either. Can you post a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: so in the middle of taking the screenshot I found something that might be of use, both `overflowX:hidden;` and `margin:0;` on the `center-column` class seem to be having a positive affect on the layout. have I just messed up the margins or something? [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/XgBbkZY.png)

Comment: Woops, sorry. Obviously I wasn't paying attention when I saw the codepen, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the file semantic.css in your codepen has `height: 100%;` for the body. This, combined with the 2em top margin in your own CSS, causes the total height of the document to be 100% + 2em high, or always higher than the viewport, no matter how large the content is.

The solution is simple: just put `body {height:auto;}` in your own CSS to set iot back to the default, and then the scrollbar will only appear if there is content to scroll to!
(Please note that in that case, the footer will partially obscure the content, because it's above it in the stacking order, but that is a completely different problem.)

```css
html body {height:auto;} /* new! */

footer{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  margin:0;
  
  bottom:0;
  
  height:12%;
  width:100%;
  background-color:red;
  
}

.center-column{
  height:auto;
  width:32%;
  
  
  margin: 2em 0px 0px 35%;
}

button.ui.button{
  margin-bottom:0.75em;  
}

textarea.text_input{
    border: solid;
    background-color:#62ddfc;
   
    overflow:hidden;
    
    margin-bottom:8%;
    padding:20px 25px 0px 25px;
  
    height:4em;
    width:100%;
  
    outline: none;
    color:white;
  
    font-size:22pt;
    
    resize: none;
}

textarea:focus{
  border:none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}




.address_box-title{
  font-family:"sans-serif";
  font-size:28pt; 
  width:auto;
  margin:20px 2% 10px 2%;
}


p.content{
  
}


@media screen and (max-width:600px){
  .center-column{
    margin-left:10%;
    width: 80%;
  }
  
  footer{
    height:16em;

  }


}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/simplebar@latest/dist/simplebar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.1/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='center-column'>
  <h2 class='address_box-title'>This is the title that I wish to give this piece of work</h2>
  <textarea class='text_input'></textarea>
  <button class='ui button'>kjkljklj</button>
  <p class='content'>This is a slice of text that I'm serving up to you as a placeholder for all the fabulous content that will be put in here later on.</p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for. I knew it was just a little mistake but I couldn't find where. Thanks!